# Display post list from JSON API response

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following JSON

```
{
   "posts":[
      {
         "id":"5efb6946eab44526aecc0aaf",
         "title":"post 2Test",
         "slug":"post-2test",
         "html":"<p>Test post 2... Testing 123 testing 123</p>",
         "feature_image":null,
         "excerpt": "Test post 1"
      },
      {
         "id":"5efb6936eab44526aecc0aa9",
         "title":"Test Post",
         "slug":"test-post",
         "html":"<p>Test post one... Testing 123</p>",
         "feature_image":null,
       "excerpt": "Test post 2"
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "pagination":{
         "page":1,
         "limit":15,
         "pages":1,
         "total":2,
         "next":null,
         "prev":null
      }
   }
}
```

How would I create a section that lists all the current posts and any that are added?

for example
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post"> <!-- this would contain the information from the most recent post -->
       <img src={featured_img} alt="featured img">
       <h2>{title}</h2>
       <p>{excerpt}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post"> <!-- this would contain the info of the second most recent post -->
       <img src={featured_img} alt="featured img">
       <h2>{title}</h2>
       <p>{excerpt}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My  guess is some kind of for loop but I am not quite sure how to write it.

Comment: I would suggest you to look into webcomponents https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `for` loop to iterate through your `json` data and get value for particular key and assign the generated `html` to your `div`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your response
var response = {
  "posts": [{
      "id": "5efb6946eab44526aecc0aaf",
      "title": "post 2Test",
      "slug": "post-2test",
      "html": "<p>Test post 2... Testing 123 testing 123</p>",
      "feature_image": null,
      "excerpt": "Test post 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "5efb6936eab44526aecc0aa9",
      "title": "Test Post",
      "slug": "test-post",
      "html": "<p>Test post one... Testing 123</p>",
      "feature_image": null,
      "excerpt": "Test post 2"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "limit": 15,
      "pages": 1,
      "total": 2,
      "next": null,
      "prev": null
    }
  }
};

 
  var html = '';
  //looping through posts
 
  for(var i= 0 ; i<response.posts.length ;i++ ){
  //get values
   html += '<div class="post" data-value='+response.posts[i].id+'><img src='+response.posts[i].feature_image+' alt="featured img"><h2>'+response.posts[i].title+'</h2><p>'+response.posts[i].excerpt+'</p></div>';
 
  }
  //add to div
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML= html;
```

```html
<div class="container" id="data">
  <!--here data will come-->
</div>
```

Comment: I’d prefer not to use jquery

Comment: Sorry , i saw the tags you added in your question after answering :)  ..i have updated my answer with pure javascript check if that works for you .

Comment: Works perfectly, though I had to change response to data within the loop. Thanks for the help, I knew what to do it was just how to write it

Comment: It's better to use `appendChild(node)` rather than setting `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by a few steps,

1. First, add ids to the divs.
2. Now add script tag which will invoke the javascript code. (I don't know which framework you are using if your framework handles it then ignore this step).
3. Now use `Json.parse(response)` to convert to JavaScript object in your javascript file, now use filters/similar functions, and find the recent one and remaining posts.
4. Now use document object to invoke you div by using unique ids that you created as part of point 1, now assign/create you Html there.

Hope this helps.